# Using iCloud for User Prefs by way of CloudKit

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

Swift 2.0, iOS9

In my App, I can save a user's prefs by way of iCloud. The first time they try to post, the data framework is setup, and the users private DB is all theirs, great, can store it all there. Fantastic!

Sounds like the Holy Grail, easy, secure, no logins, loving it, BUT when the App try's to access the saved records, this is spit back at me:

```
Optional(<CKError 0x12462cc60: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2015); server message = "Field '___recordID' is not marked queryable";
```

And there seems to be no one of updating in code, so how do I retrieve data from iCloud if I can't update that setting?  Most be a way?  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the [CloudKit Dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard) to mark the Record ID property of this record type as queryable.

Select your record type and click on "Metadata Indexes". Check the Query checkbox next to the Record ID field and this error should go away.

Comment: Yes, but the App is being launched from someone else's cell phone. So it's their iCloud. They are just downloading the App, so I have no access to that dashboard. That's the quandary. Saving is fine, retrieving data is not. I also have to mark the creationTime field as sort-able.

Comment: The dashboard manages container-wide settings. Record Type settings are part of the container schema and apply to all users. You can read more in the [CloudKit Dashboard documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I have no access to a users CloudKit Dashboard. Maybe I'm missing something fundamental here. The user can save Prefs to Cloud Kit, the issue is that can't retrive them since the index on their CloudKit is not tagged "queryable". There must be a way I get set that up. Looking through docs, all say to update in 'My CloudKit Dashboard".  Thanks for help.

Comment: The dashboard is not for users- it's where developers (presumably you) configure their entire CloudKit container.

Comment: One other thing to note is that only new records will be found by recordID after you make this change. The server won't index existing records in the database.

Comment: Ok, so guess If I have 10,000 App users, they're all really in my App's "Container", sitting on Apple's servers. Even if I have them write their saved User Prefs to the private database, it's still in my "Container." And controlled in my dashboard.  I could also simultaneously save each users User Prefs to the Public Database. That way I also have the "Most Liked AKA Popular" data to chart. Thanks for reply.